# dplyr cross tab with missing values (updated 2022)

Tags: r, data-analysis

Would it be possible to update the answer given here:

[dplyr cross tab with missing values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29108431/dplyr-cross-tab-with-missing-values)

code:

```
library(tidyr)
mtcars %>%
  mutate(
    cyl = ifelse(cyl > 6, NA, cyl),
    gear = ifelse(gear > 4, NA, gear)
  ) %>%
  group_by(cyl, gear) %>%
  tally() %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate_each(funs(replace(., is.na(.), 'missing'))) %>%
  spread(gear, n)
```

There appear to be some deprecated functions (mutate_each, funs and spread) in the suggested code so sadly it doesn't work.

I'm trying to get up to speed with R doing the same things I normally do with Stata.

Tried to run the code as per original post.

Comment: While it's nice that you brought attention to this old question, I'd suggest closing this question and moving answers to the original question

Comment: I'd be more than happy to, but I can't see any options available to me as a new user to do that

Comment: I'll close this question as duplicate. @Jon Spring, feel free to add your answer to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyr); library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
  mutate(
    cyl = ifelse(cyl > 6, NA, cyl),
    gear = ifelse(gear > 4, NA, gear)
  ) %>%
  count(cyl, gear) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~coalesce(as.character(.), "missing"))) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = gear, values_from = n)

# A tibble: 3 × 4
  cyl     `3`   `4`   missing
  <chr>   <chr> <chr> <chr>  
1 4       1     8     2      
2 6       2     4     1      
3 missing 12    NA    2
```

Comment: I did not see that solution here, but it might be preferable to add this answer to the original question

Comment: Thank you so much for the immediate response, super appreciated!